# How to fix LTSA error

Tags: state-machine

We are using the Labelled Transition System Analyser in class, and we're supposed to fix the following:

```
ROTATOR = in_PAUSED.
in_PAUSED = (Run -> in_RUN | Pause -> in_PAUSED | Interrupt -> STOP).
in_RUN = (Pause -> in_PAUSED || {Run,Rotate} -> in_RUN).
```

I know that the actions Run, Pause, Interrupt should follow the conventions of starting with lower case, and similarly processes being identified using uppercase.

```
ROTATOR = In_PAUSED.
In_PAUSED = (run -> In_RUN | pause -> In_PAUSED | interrupt -> STOP).
In_RUN = (pause -> In_PAUSED || {run,rotate} -> In_RUN).
```

However, after I compile this, I get an error: ERROR line:3 - ) expected. I don't really know how to fix it after this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer

```
ROTATOR = In_PAUSED ,
In_PAUSED = ( run -> In_RUN | pause -> In_PAUSED | interrupt -> STOP ) ,
In_RUN = ( pause -> In_PAUSED | {run , rotate} -> In_RUN ) .
```

LOLOL I am in the same class.